# How do Gmail plugins such as Rapportive work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I know Gmail has contextual and side-bar gadgets, but how do browser extensions such as Rapportive work? Are they injecting their buttons / displays into the browser page? If so, wouldn't the browser extension break if Google decided to change the way they layout the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are they injecting their buttons / displays into the browser page?

Yes.

> If so, wouldn't the browser extension break if Google decided to change the way they layout the page?

Probably.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - is this conjecture or known fact?

Comment: It's a very educated guess.  I'm not 100% positive (only the devs of the extension know) but I'm pretty confident that I'm right.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

The probably leverage some part of the [Gmail Greasemonkey API](http://code.google.com/p/gmail-greasemonkey/wiki/GmailGreasemonkey10API) and inject scripts into the page to use this.